# Angularjs ui-rangeSlider onHandleUp

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Here is the HTML

```
<div range-slider min="0" max="100" model-max="rangevalue.value" pin-handle="min" onHandleUp="x()"></div>
```

and i want to do something like this.

```
$scope.x=function(){
 console.log($scope.rangevalue.value)
}
```

but onHandleUp is not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `on-handle-up` and not `onHandleUp` inside your div.

Btw and fyi, [onHandleUp doesn't call $apply](https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider/issues/32).